# Is it possible to retrieve information about articles in multiple languages without multiple requests?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I mean this methot where user can ask data for max 50 articles without abusing api system by multiple requests, so:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=size&titles=Berlin|Paris|Rome

Gives correct size for these articles. But how to retrieve such info about sizes from different languages ? The only method I know of is to replace the language code at the beginning of the domain, like this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=size&titles=Berlin

https://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=size&titles=Berlin

https://sv.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=size&titles=Berlin

etc..

So natural question is how to make these requests into one, but all I try do not work.

for example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=size&titles=en:Berlin|de:Berlin|sv:Berlin - shows only data for English page, for others there is only a strange entry for example: `{ "title": "sv:berlin", "iw": "sv" }` that contains no useful data

removing the country code from domain also breaks the query: https://wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=size&titles=en:Berlin|de:Berlin|sv:Berlin - `"invalidreason": "The requested page title contains invalid characters: \"%7c\"."`

So is the only way to get such data to try to gently 'flood' their api servers and hope that they wouldn't block me ?

Comment: Each language version is hosted on a different server. Use multiple requests. What exactly are you trying to do that might "flood" the servers?

Comment: If I need to get size of all articles from different languages referring to for example 'Berlin' that would be lot of requests... my ip may get blocked from using API.

Comment: I don't think that even requests to [all 225 Berlin pages](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q64#sitelinks-wikipedia) would get you blocked, as long as you don't fire such searches continously. A single shot won't hurt. Alternatively, maybe http://vs.aka-online.de/cgi-bin/globalwpsearch.pl?search=Berlin could help, altough it only works for exact page names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to bundle those requests in one, especially as they are very cheap API requests. Just make all the requests you need.